# How to make XML request with SoapClient?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am having a hard time understanding how to generate proper XML requests using `SoapClient` in PHP. I am trying to generate the following sample XML requests.

```
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>
   <OTA_HotelAvailReq RequestedCurrency="INR">
       <AvailRequestSegments>
            <AvailRequestSegment>
                <HotelSearchCriteria>
                     <Criterion>
                          <Address>
                              <CityName code="BNG">Bangalore</CityName>
                          </Address>
                          <GuestCounts>
                              <GuestCount AgeQualifyingCode="10" />
                              <GuestCount Age="10 />
                          </GuestCounts>
                     </Criterion>
                </HotelSearchCriteria>
            </AvailRequestSegment>
       </AvailRequestSegments>
   </OTA_HotelAvailReq>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My question is how to use `SoapClient` and form this XML data.

Comment: Why did you post this again as a new question 15 minutes after posting a [**nearly identical question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30754865/290085) which already has received an answer to which you've not responded?

Comment: I figured that was a bad question - this one is more concise which I think will make it easier to answer and understand. Also, I couldn't understand the answer. [Note - Deleted my previous question]. Can you help me with this question? Thanks.